# How to use or setup P2P / Cloud based connections between Apache servers?

Tags: php, apache, p2p

I've been scouring through P2P documents but I can't seem to get the right info because most are talking about P2P file sharing or VOIP.

My question is actually about HTTP connection between two machines using P2P or cloud-based hand shake.

To make it simple, I have a client-to-client LAMP based application. The application is basically a browser based PHP software running on a small server.

Office A and Office B each has a server with my application running, and each server needs to talk to one another HTTP GET/POSTS.

My application works fine if each office has a public IP and routers are configured properly.

But now my problem is that REAL WORLD use of this needs to be independent of internet connection type and network configurations.

I noticed that more and more devices like IP cameras and DVR now feature P2P connections w/c makes it really easy to connect devices even through firewalls.

Basically the devices has a pre-set IP/Domain name w/c is for the P2P server..

I also learned that data is not a burden on the P2P server because data does not go through the P2P server anymore but rather only a sort of "hand shake is made" between the two devices through the P2P server , then the data goes to and from DIRECTLY between the 2 devices....

This is what I want to mimic for my application.

Is it possible for a LAMP based client application? Is it really complicated? Are there any ready made P2P servers that's easy to install and configure for my purpose?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Do you want two or more web servers to sync data? If so, I don't think you need P2P here. Just use cURL on each, pointing at the other server, or perhaps Rsync in the background.

Comment: What does "w/c" mean?

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'easy' way to do p2p and no module or technique for doing it with php or apache.

p2p applications like BitTorrent or earlier versions of Skype typically work by communicating with your router to effectively open the port that the other clients will connect to. If you can't open the port on your router you have to have both clients connect to a 3rd party server and route requests through that.

There are a few libraries for connecting Java Tomcat or Jetty servers with p2p but they aren't often used in production. You 'could' try running a java based PHP implementation on top of one of them, but I think what you want to do probably isn't worth the effort.

If I was asked to do this I would do one of the following:

- establish a permanent VPN connection between the 2 offices so they can see each other's servers
- place a server on the public net outside of both offices and have them both communicate with that.

Comment: Hi terrence, thanks for that man. VPN is not viable for my purpose . i really just need to mimic how these cloud based IP cameras work .. so option 2 may be something that will work for me. but that means changing the design drastically right? where both sides will need to put data on server and server will hand it to and from each side? like a middle man? i was hoping of just the server facilitating initial link then both sides can comms directly. guess that's off the table?